# If and For Statements

Tags: matlab

Is it possible to compare an element with a previous element without using a `for` loop and `if` statement in Matlab?

For instance:

```
     X = [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2] 
     for n = 1:length(X)
         if (X(n) ~= X(n-1))
```

Comment: Note that your for loop would actually break. You would need something like `n = 2:length(X)`

Answer (score 3):

If they are numbers, yes:

```
diff(X)==0
```

will give you all the elements which are equal to the previous element.

Comment: I was going to suggest `X(2:end) ~= X(1:end-1)`, but surprisingly the `diff` method actually exhibits better performance. +1

Comment: Strictly speaking your statement will give you a logical array with the elements corresponding to the condition set to `true`. To return the elements, you would need something like `X(diff(X)==0)`

Comment: Note that it also works for characters. Try: `~diff([0 0 12 12 'a' 'a'])` (Characters, not strings)

Answer (score 1):

`find(diff(X)~=0)` will return the indices of the elements you are looking for (maybe offset by one).